# Prepared statement fails in a function - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, return, prepared-statement

I don't know why but this function returns false when I try to use prepared statements in it however, when I use non-prepared statements it returns true. Can anyone explain it?
**Code:**

```
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
    $sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id=? AND username=? AND password=? AND activated=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conx->prepare($sql);
    $var = 1;
    $stmt->bind_param("issi",$id,$u,$p,$var);
    $stmt->execute();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

$user_ok = evalLoggedUser($conn,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
```

This returns false

```
function evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p){
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND username='$u' AND password='$p' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows > 0){
        return true;
    }
}
$user_ok = evalLoggedUser($conn,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password);
```

This returns true

Comment: Have you checked your web server's error logs?

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: `evalLoggedUser($conx,$id,$u,$p)` and `evalLoggedUser($conn,$log_id,$log_username,$log_password)` and `bind_param("issi",$id,$u,$p,$var)` something doesn't add up here, that's the problem here. And error reporting would have told you about it.

Comment: Pus, using `num_rows` before storing the data into memory might give unexpected results.

Comment: I'm curious how the first example supposedly returns `false` when the only possibilities are `true` and nothing, aka `null`. Additionally, all of those mysqli function calls have return values that you're not bothering to check. I'll bet there's some useful info there.

Comment: Maybe it's related to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289) on the docs (call `store_result` first.)

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you help me understand [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183965/prepared-statement-fails-in-a-function-php/46224516#comment79330763_46183965), please? How is that the problem? Is what you saw the same as the answer below? I can't see it :\ :\ (It's probably something literally in my face)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is a simple typographical mistake: you pass 4 parameters as prepared, but expect 5.

See this: `$stmt->bind_param(/*"issi",*/$id,$u,$p,$var);`

Comment: Thank you this works but I have already found the solution. I forget to mention that the `activated` is `enum` type  and I tried to pass the enum as an `integer` but if I pass it as `string` it also works nice.

Comment: Why was this upvoted and selected as the correct answer? TBH I don't see it (what is said in the answer..) am I going crazy?

Comment: Why does it expect 5 parameters? There are 4 placeholders (`?`), four letters (`issi`) and four variables (`$id`, `$u`, `$p`, `$var`)...